# Force Client to reconnect to ftp server

Tags: windows, sockets, ftp, port, ftp-client

so the case is: Client is in ftp session with server and how could i corrupt the connection so user would have to reconnect again? I'm thinking about blocking the clients ftp port, how could i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing to do is to add and enable a firewall rule from the Control Panel. You can even do it programmatically with the Windows Firewall API including from script.